# Sudden error/bug on a working code in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title suggests, I encountered an unexpected error in my code, which was working fine until I attempted to edit or change a single line of code. The error message that keeps appearing is "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object," which is a common problem for many people.

The line of code that was causing the error was line 23.

```
1  using System;
2  using System.IO;
3  using UnityEngine;
4  using UnityEngine.Rendering;
5 
6  public class SaveImage : MonoBehaviour {
7 
8     public static SaveImage Instance { get; private set; }
9 
10    [SerializeField] private Camera screenshotCamera;
11 
12     private Action<Texture2D> onScreenshotTaken;
13 
14     private void Awake() {
15         Instance = this;
16         RenderPipelineManager.endFrameRendering += RenderPipelineManager_endFrameRendering;
17     }
18 
19     private void RenderPipelineManager_endFrameRendering(ScriptableRenderContext arg1, Camera[] arg2) {
20         if (onScreenshotTaken != null) {
21             RenderTexture renderTexture = screenshotCamera.targetTexture;
22 
23             Texture2D renderResult = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
24             Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height);
25             renderResult.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);
26             renderResult.Apply();
27 
28             RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTexture);
29             screenshotCamera.targetTexture = null;
30 
31             onScreenshotTaken(renderResult);
32             onScreenshotTaken = null;
33 
34             Destroy(renderResult);
35         }
36     }
37 
38     public void Save() {
39 
40        TakeScreenshot(Screen.width, Screen.height, (Texture2D screenshotTexture) => {
41             string pathfile = Application.persistentDataPath + "/NGallery/ImageData.png";
42             string imagestorage = pathfile;
43             byte[] screenshotByteArray = screenshotTexture.EncodeToPNG();
44             File.WriteAllBytes(imagestorage, screenshotByteArray);
45         });
46     }
47 
48     private void TakeScreenshot(int width, int height, Action<Texture2D> onScreenshotTaken) {
49         screenshotCamera.targetTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(width, height, 16);
50         this.onScreenshotTaken = onScreenshotTaken;
51     }
52 }
```

What I've tried and it's results:

- Tried loading back my old Unity Project. - Working fine.
- Tried to create everything from scratch. - Error Occurs.
- Tried copy and pasting my old Unity Project. - Error Occurs.
- Tried Debugging the renderTexture in the New Unity Project with
  Debug.Log(renderTexture) saying it's null.
- Tried Debugging the renderTexture in the old Unity Project with
  Debug.Log(renderTexture) saying it's not null and working.

Comment: I think this `screenshotCamera.targetTexture = null;` creating an issue. when this particular method is called more than once. because it will set `screenshotCamera.targetTexture` to null and you will get an exception when you try to use it again

Comment: Weird thing is, my screenshotCamera isn't set to null, since I have `[SerializeField] private Camera screenshotCamera;` which I already placed my Camera Gameobject into it.

Comment: The `screenshotCamera.targetTexture` can still be `null`  when the `screenshotCamera` is not ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, somehow I've fixed the problem, it has got to do with the file Directory where the Image is saved(I don't know how it's related, but I'm sure that this is causing the problem, and I even tried to double check if it's really the File Directory). So, what I did is, I added a new line in `Line 41 Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/NGallery");` moving down a Line`string pathfile = Application.persistentDataPath + "/NGallery/ImageData.png";` to Line 42. Then no error occurs anymore.

Comment: This will solve a directory not found exception ... This doesn't really make sense regarding your question though. This code change can not fix a `NullReferenceException` ... I suspect that maybe before your code wasn't recompiled yet

Comment: It doesn't, but somehow I'm not receiving any NullReferenceException anymore, I even tried doing ```Debug.Log(screenshotCamera.targetTexture)``` as well as ```Console.WriteLine(screenshotCamera.targetTexture)``` and it didn't give me ```Null``` anymore, instead it now give ```TempBuffer 9059 1080x2160 (UnityEngine.RenderTexture)``` which I want as the result.

Comment: But if I don't add ```Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/NGallery");``` in my code, both ```Debug.Log(screenshotCamera.targetTexture)``` and ```Console.WriteLine(screenshotCamera.targetTexture)``` will give me an output ```Null``` and not ```TempBuffer 9059 1080x2160 (UnityEngine.RenderTexture)```.